# What is the complement (or negation) of, "The function is one-to-one and onto."

Tags: functions, logic

What is the complement (or negation) of, "The function is one-to-one and onto."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we negate the conjunction,

"It is *not* the case that (the function is one-to-one AND onto)"

Then by DeMorgan's we have:

"The function is *not* one-to-one **OR** it is *not* onto.

Comment: This is pretty much as good as we're going to get, unless you prefer something about no matching existing between domain and codomain.

Comment: Using demorgan's right.  I should have extended the question, but someone is trying to tell me that "The function is many-to-one and not onto." is also an answer.  Which seems incorrect.

Comment: That someone is incorrect.

Comment: You are right, it is incorrect. The correct negation is the one given in the solution by @amWhy.

Comment: Well, a function can only be one-to-one or many-to-one, right? So would "The function f is many-to-one OR not onto." be correct also?

Comment: Yes, it is correct, because saying that the function is many-to-one is the same that saying it is not one-to-one.

Answer (score 2):

The function is not bijective.